# How to route specific VPN traffic via specific VPN client?

Tags: debian, iptables, routing, openvpn, vpn

I have VPN network based on OpenVPN software. I need route all network traffic in VPN network where destination IP is from specific country via one specific client on this VPN network (VPN client IP address) - Mikrotik router where is configured NAT (MASQUERADE) for main internet interface (PPPoE). I need get public, dynamic IP address owned by this VPN client (Mikrotik router - PPPoE interface) for all this traffic. So on VPN server I created iptables mangle rule and I use geoip iptables module:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i tun0 -m geoip --destination-country COUNTRY_CODE -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

So I have marked all traffic from client which have destination IP from this specific country. Next I have tried use this [solution](http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/iproute2.html): Create specific route table and add default route. But default route can be only for next hop on this network. So when I use this command:

```
ip route add default via specific_VPN_client dev tun0 table CountryRoute
```

I get this error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

Is possible route specific traffic to specific client, but not to next hop please?

I tried this iptables rule too:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -m geoip --destination-country COUNTRY_CODE -j DNAT --to-destination Mikrotik_VPN_IP
```

But traffic ends on Mikrotik router. Maybe would be possible solve this problem on this router?

OpenVPN server (10.1.1.1) route table:

```
default via PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER dev eth0
10.1.1.0/24 via 10.1.1.2 dev tun0
10.1.1.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.1
PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER
```

**UPDATE**

I used this [solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/642327/change-openvpn-servers-tun0-address-from-xxx-xxx-xxx-1-to-xxx-xxx-xxx-11) for adding default route in CountryRoute table. So CountryRoute table has this content:

```
default via 10.1.1.30 dev tun0
```

I have active iptables mangle rule (mentioned above) and ip route rules:

```
ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
32765:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup CountryRoute
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

But marked traffic still ends on 10.1.1.1 - OpenVPN server, it does not continue to Mikrotik router.

**UPDATE2**

Currently values:

```
default via PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER dev eth0
10.0.0.0/24 dev veth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1
10.0.1.0/24 dev veth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.2
10.1.1.0/24 via 10.1.1.30 dev tun0
10.1.1.30 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.1
PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.1.1.1  P-t-P:10.1.1.30  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER/64 Scope:Global
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:141437 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:230785 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:14693683 (14.0 MiB)  TX bytes:240387315 (229.2 MiB)

ip route show table CountryRoute
default via 10.1.1.30 dev tun0
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
ip -4 route show table all
default via 10.0.0.2 dev veth0 table CountryRoute
default via PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER_gateway dev eth0 onlink
10.0.0.0/24 dev veth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
10.0.1.0/24 dev veth3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2
10.1.1.0/24 via 10.1.1.30 (Mikrotik_VPN_IP) dev tun0
10.1.1.30 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.1.1
PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER
broadcast 10.0.0.0 dev veth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
local 10.0.0.1 dev veth0 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.0.0.1
broadcast 10.0.0.255 dev veth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
broadcast 10.0.1.0 dev veth3 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2
local 10.0.1.2 dev veth3 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.0.1.2
broadcast 10.0.1.255 dev veth3 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2
local 10.1.1.1 dev tun0 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.1.1.1
broadcast PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER_networkIP dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER
local PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope host src PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER
broadcast PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER_broadcastIP dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
```

**UPDATE 4**

```
ip netns exec Mikrotik ip -4 route show table all
default via 10.0.1.2 dev veth2
10.0.0.0/24 dev veth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2
10.0.1.0/24 dev veth2 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.1
10.1.1.30 via 10.0.1.2 dev veth2
broadcast 10.0.0.0 dev veth1 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2
local 10.0.0.2 dev veth1 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.0.0.2
broadcast 10.0.0.255 dev veth1 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2
broadcast 10.0.1.0 dev veth2 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.1
local 10.0.1.1 dev veth2 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.0.1.1
broadcast 10.0.1.255 dev veth2 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.1
```

**UPDATE 5**

```
# ip netns exec Mikrotik traceroute -I 10.1.1.30
traceroute to 10.1.1.30 (10.1.1.30), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.1.2 (10.0.1.2)  0.053 ms  0.016 ms  0.013 ms
 2  10.1.1.30 (10.1.1.30)  18.868 ms  38.147 ms  98.549 ms

# ip netns exec Mikrotik traceroute 10.1.1.30
traceroute to 10.1.1.30 (10.1.1.30), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.1.2 (10.0.1.2)  0.056 ms  0.019 ms  0.016 ms
 2  10.1.1.30 (10.1.1.30)  19.044 ms  37.808 ms  56.347 ms

# ip netns exec Mikrotik traceroute COUNTRY_PUBLIC_IP_MARKED_TRAFFIC
traceroute to COUNTRY_PUBLIC_IP_MARKED_TRAFFIC (COUNTRY_PUBLIC_IP_MARKED_TRAFFIC), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.1.1 (10.0.1.1)  3052.269 ms !H  3052.212 ms !H  3052.185 ms !H

# ip netns exec Mikrotik traceroute -I COUNTRY_PUBLIC_IP_MARKED_TRAFFIC
traceroute to COUNTRY_PUBLIC_IP_MARKED_TRAFFIC (COUNTRY_PUBLIC_IP_MARKED_TRAFFIC), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * 10.0.1.1 (10.0.1.1)  3067.929 ms !H  3067.883 ms !H
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The next hop must be determined, and this is what we call _routing_. However, in an OpenVPN setup each client is one hop away _inside the VPN_, so I don't understand why you can't use that. You may want to reword the description of your setup, I'm having trouble following it.

Comment: @FerencWágner many thanks for your reply. I added route table of my OpenVPN server in main post. I need route all marked traffic from tun0 to 10.1.1.30 (VPN IP address of my Mikrotik router). Is it possible please? When I try this: ip route add default via 10.1.1.30 dev tun0 table CountryRoute I get error Network is unreachable... Thanks.

Comment: I would try adding an explicit route for 10.1.1.30 via tun0. Or make openVPN use a tap rather than tun, so that ARP resolution works for the client.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist Thanks. Now I used this solution https://serverfault.com/questions/642327/change-openvpn-servers-tun0-address-from-xxx-xxx-xxx-1-to-xxx-xxx-xxx-11 and I have default route to 10.1.1.30, but traffic still does not pass via tun0. Any idea where can be problem please? Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with the new information.

Comment: Why don't you run 2 openVPN servers, with one dedicated for the Microtec router, and then route the other into that?

Comment: @RalphRönnquist I am thinking about this option too. But first I wanted to know possible solution within one VPN network...

Comment: It's probably too hard to route a packet back into the interface it came from without the networking layers getting sulky. Most likely it'll need a separate namespace for making a loop with masquerading and whatnot. Two openVPN seems easier.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist thanks for info, I understand, but do you know any example or instruction please? I would like to try it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the set up of a network namespace for receiving the Mikrotik traffic, and route it back with NAT to the actual Mikrotik could be done via the following, using 10.0.0.0/24 "into" the namespace and 10.0.1.0/24 back out, then routed via the Mikrotik_VPN_IP

```
ip netns add Mikrotik
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
ip link set veth1 netns Mikrotik
ip link add veth2 type veth peer name veth3
ip link set veth2 netns Mikrotik
ifconfig veth0 10.0.0.1/24 up
ifconfig veth3 10.0.1.2/24 up
ip netns exec Mikrotik ifconfig veth1 10.0.0.2/24 up
ip netns exec Mikrotik ifconfig veth2 10.0.1.1/24 up
ip netns exec Mikrotik iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o veth2 -j MASQUERADE
ip netns exec Mikrotik ip route add Mikrotik_VPN_IP via 10.0.1.2
ip netns exec Mikrotik ip route add default via Mikrotik_VPN_IP dev veth2 onlink
ip netns exec Mikrotik iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -j MARK --set-mark 0
```

With that, you have a traffic path to/from the Microtek router by routing it via 10.0.0.2. You also need the rule based routing to pass the selected traffic via 10.0.0.2, and the rest via the "normal"/default route.

Comment: many thanks! But last command gives me this error:
`ip netns exec Mikrotik ip route add default via 10.1.1.30
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`

Comment: You do have `10.1.1.30 via 10.1.1.2 dev tun0` in the default route table? The CountryRoute table should have `default via 10.0.0.2`. By using a tun rather than tap, the ARP doesn't work, so you can't rely on the network route.

Comment: I updated main post with currently values (UPDATE2). So now I have to change default via 10.0.0.2 in CountryRoute?

Comment: Yes, you want those incoming packets from tun0 to be routed via 10.0.0.2 (the namespace), where they will be routed onwards via 10.1.1.30. With NAT, i.e., they will be sourced from 10.0.1.1.

Comment: ok thanks. So now I have: `ip route show table ContryRoute`:
`default via 10.0.0.2 dev veth0` But command: `ip netns exec Mikrotik ip route add default via 10.1.1.30` still gives error: `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`

Comment: correctly: `ip netns exec Mikrotik ip route add default via 10.0.1.2` great! It works! I will test it yet for finally verification and I will let you know... Many thanks! And what is the easiest way makes these changes permanently (after reboot) please?

Comment: Right; I had forgotten naming the namespace. But I'm unsure now about the last two for your working set up. Is my edit right, or should they be different? ... as for setup at boot; I'd put them in a script, and then make that script be run late at boot time. Exact details depends on which OS+version you're using.

Comment: I tested this solution and works perfect, I created startup bash script too, many thanks!

Comment: after upgrade Debian from 8 to 9 unfortunatelly it does not work. :-( I can reach only IP 10.1.1.1 (VPN server), 10.0.1.1 and 10.0.1.2 after connection continues via default route (PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER dev eth0) and it does not continue to Mikrotik router. :-( Can you help me please? All data in my post are still valid.

Comment: You mean that eg `ip netns exec Microtik ping google.com` does not make traffic via Mictrotic_VPN_IP? Or is it the "outer" routing that fails (to direct traffic through the netns)?

Comment: many thanks for your quick reply. Ping works, but when I try traceroute next hop is 10.0.1.2 and next gateway of PUBLIC_IP_VPN_SERVER and after common route... It does not route this traffic to my Mikrotik router...

Comment: You'll need to confirm the routing table with the network namespace, that its default route is to the Mikrotik. `ip -4 route show table all`.

Comment: I added output of `ip -4 route show table all` to main post - UPDATE 3. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, you might also need that from within the netns: `ip netns exec Mikrotik ip -4 route show table all` since that's the routing that fails, isn't it.

Comment: I added output of `ip netns exec Mikrotik ip -4 route show table all` to main post - UPDATE 4. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. As you can see, the default route in the netns is wrong (going to 10.0.1.2). Delete that, and add again the last line from above, i.e., the default route to tne Mikrotik (10.1.1.30). Note that that IP must be available when the default route is set. Not sure how the faulty default route got set.

Comment: Thanks, But when I add `ip netns exec Mikrotik ip route add default via 10.1.1.30` I get error: `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`, `ip netns exec Mikrotik ping 10.1.1.30` works ok. What Can I add 10.1.1.30 as defult route please? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. odd. maybe it needs the `lo` interface to be up in the netns? `ip netns exec Mikrotik ip link set lo up`. In a vague memory this (i.e., `lo` being up by default)  is something that changed with some kernel update at some while ago ... othewise I'm a bit at a loss.

Comment: Unfortunately It does not help :-( I still get error: `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`

Comment: I just now realized I used "Microtek" for the netns rather than "Mikrotik" in the reply. That's a bad misspelling; sorry about that.... hopefully it's not that causing this problem. Maybe I should correct the reply?

Comment: it is OK I used always correct "Mkrotik", but problem still remains :-( Any other idea please?

Comment: Otherwise it's just that "wrong" default route of the netns; how does that come there? at the same time it shouldn't "be in the way" as there is a static route to 10.1.1.30? or maybe the default route "disturbs" already the static route? maybe start from scratch and check between each command, to delete the "wrong" default route as soon as it appears.

Comment: I tried from scratch but result is the same. When I remove `ip netns exec Mikrotik ip route del 10.1.1.30 via 10.0.1.2 dev veth2` and after add default route: `ip netns exec Mikrotik ip route add default via 10.1.1.30 dev tun0` I get error: `Cannot find device "tun0"` Maybe only solution with create new VPN network will solve it :-(

Comment: Two things: (1) `dev tun0` is wrong and not part of the script. Then (2), the bad route is the one showing up as `default via 10.0.1.2 dev veth2`. That one should not be there at all, and I can't understand how it came there if you followed the script in my reply (only replace all Microtek with Mikrotik). You do need the static route to 10.1.1.30 via 10.0.1.2, so shouldn't remove that one. All in all, that's why I suggested you go from start and check the netns routing table after each command, so as to remove that bad default route whenever it comes up.

Comment: ok, when I started from scratch the last step of script is unsuccessful `ip netns exec Mikrotik ip route add default via 10.1.1.30` usually I get error message: `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Maybe it helps adding an `onlink` directive at the end... i.e. `ip netns exec Microtek ip route add default via Mikrotik_VPN_IP onlink`

Comment: I get error message: `RTNETLINK answers: No such device` :-(

Comment: hmm. maybe it needs `dev veth2` (these `ip` commands are abstruse). i.e., `ip netns exec Microtek ip route add default via Mikrotik_VPN_IP dev veth2 onlink`... but it feels a bit like random juggling now :(

Comment: great `ip netns exec Mikrotik ip route add default via 10.1.1.30 dev veth2 onlink` was accepted but marked traffic (for specific country) ends on 10.1.1.1 now... :-(

Comment: Maybe it was merely that the outer space rule to `10.1.1.30` that needs an `onlink`, (since the kernel won't get an ARP response for a tun connection); I think that could explain why setting the inner route setting fails. The next might be due to the mark surviving the masquerading, and for that you'd need to reset the mark within the netns.

Comment: Thanks. 1. What you mean with "outer space rule" please? 2. And what way I have to reset the mark within the netns please? Thanks.

Comment: "outer space" = "update 3"; route `10.1.1.30 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.1.1`  might need `onlink`, and I updated the commands in the reply with the onlink directive, and a reset of the mark within the netns.

Comment: you mean `route 10.1.1.0/24 via 10.1.1.30 dev tun0`? `ip route add 10.1.1.0/24 via 10.1.1.30 dev tun0 onlink`? After I have added reset of the mark within the netns marked traffic (for specific country) still ends on 10.1.1.1

Comment: It's more than peculiar that ICMP (ping inside netns) finds the route to 10.1.1.30, but other traffic doesn't. (no new iptables rules, I'm sure). But yes, the "public vpn" route has an `onlink` so I'm sure the "Mikroitik vpn" route would also do well with one. I do wonder what the differences are in the kernel networking flag settings (sysctl) that cause this?

Comment: my sysctl settings: https://pastebin.com/LWkSB68h, I added UPDATE 5 in main post. It is interesting that traceroute to 10.1.1.30 is correctly done, but traceroute to IP address from specific country for marked traffic ends on 10.0.1.1...

Comment: any idea please? Maybe when I change my OpenVPN network from TUN on TAP?

Comment: It really sounds like a missing MASQUERADE rule for out-traffic on 10.1.1.1 ? Did that get lost? (I mean, there must have been one before, when it all worked) Without that, the 10.1.1.30 will be confused about delivering (return) packets to 10.0.1.1.

Comment: I have set: `-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` and
`-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.1.1.1`

Comment: should I add some other MASQUERADE rule please?